# Adding action bar and options menu to activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample for my app. This sample doesn't have an action bar.

This is the layout of activity in which I want to add an action bar with options menu:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#000"
        tools:context="com.example.android.camera2basic.CameraActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, `LinearLayout` and a `FrameLayout` inside of it as a container for fragment. In Main Activity I have implemented `onCreateOptionsMenu` and added `setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar));` but actionbar with the menu isn't appearing.

How can I add an `ActionBar` with menus to this activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a main_menu.xml in your menu folder

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:title="Option 1" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu2"
    android:title="Optiion 2" />
```

Add this in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't make an ActionBar appear in the activity, I know how to make a menu.

Comment: Are you extending AppCompatActivity and using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in style?

Answer (score 0):

Set your Activity Theme to NoActionBar and add this 2 lines of Code in your Activity onCreate method.

Add ToolBar in your Layout.

```
ToolBar toolbar = findViewById ();
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```